# Meaning of error message on QGIS start-up

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

On start up QGIS 3.36.1 on Windows 10 I get this weird error message:
[image]

```
2024-03-25T12:10:17     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/Kurt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\consolidate_networks\processing\library\consolidate_networks\consolidate_networks_algorithms.py", line 825, in initAlgorithm
              QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
             TypeError: QgsProcessingParameterNumber(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
              overload 1: argument 3 has unexpected type 'int'
              overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Anyone else having this behaviour? And what does this mean? (It did not appear under 3.34.)

Comment: Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > Uncheck the checkbox next to the plugin name.

Comment: Thanks, unchecking was not enough, I had to uninstall it. If you are willing to post your comment as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is due to the [*Consolidate Networks*](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/consolidate_networks/) plugin. If you disable (or uninstall) the plugin, the error will likely not occur anymore.

[image]

It might be a bug in the plugin, if so, it is best to contact the plugin author.